# Java: Convert List<Integer> to String

Tags: java

How can I convert `List<Integer> to String`? E.g. If my `List<Integer>` contains numbers 1 2 and 3 how can it be converted to String = "1,2,3"? Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Integer.toString() might help

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a good question and neither @GermannArlington or orangegoat have answered it.

Comment: Probably because "the question does not show any research effort".

Comment: Still, it's a useful question and from the answer it's not obvious. I think it's quite obvious that if a user is asking a question like this they are very new to the language and therefore this is a reasonable question. If there are no duplicate questions (I did't check) then that's an even stronger case. IMHO.

Comment: I've tried to find solution but I could't find solution that solves my problem. I don't understand what is wrong with my question...

Comment: @Martin, Joe: when you ask such a question, don't just ask for a solution for your problem. Show what you have tried to solve the problem, and explain what you're having problems with. This is what consitutes a "Research effort". Otherwise, it just looks like: "Hey, I'm too lazy to find out how to do this simple thing. Could anyone do it for me?".

Comment: @JB Nizet: Maybe for you is it a simple thing, but I've never do this so first I try to find sth about it but unsuccessfully, so I've asked how to do it. But OK I accept your opinion.

Comment: I'm not saying that you didn't try anything. Just that the question doesn't show that. Note that I'm not the downvoter. I'm just explaining why the downvoters probably downvoted.

Comment: Since Java 8 you can do: `numbers.stream().map(i -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way would be:

`Iterate` over list, add each item to `StringBuffer` (or) `StringBuilder` and do `toString()` at end.

Example:

```
StringBuilder strbul  = new StringBuilder();
     Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
     while(iter.hasNext())
     {
         strbul.append(iter.next());
        if(iter.hasNext()){
         strbul.append(",");
        }
     }
 strbul.toString();
```

Comment: StringBuilder if using Java 5 or greater

Comment: list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) since Java 8.

Answer (score 55):

In vanilla Java 8 (streams) you can do

```
// Given numberList is a List<Integer> of 1,2,3...

String numberString = numberList.stream().map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

// numberString here is "1,2,3"
```

Comment: Better, nicer, newer way to do it properly ++1!

Answer (score 53):

I think you may use simply `List.toString()` as below:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);


String listString = intList.toString();
System.out.println(listString); //<- this prints [1, 2, 3]
```

If you don't want `[]` in the string, simply use the substring e.g.:

```
   listString = listString.substring(1, listString.length()-1); 
   System.out.println(listString); //<- this prints 1, 2, 3
```

Please note: `List.toString()` uses `AbstractCollection#toString` method, which converts the list into String as above

Comment: The format of the string returned by AbstractCollection#toString is implementation specific I assume?

Comment: This is a bit hacky and outdated imo.

Answer (score 50):

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries):

```
String s = Joiner.on(',').join(integerList);
```

Comment: Downvoter: why the downvote? Don't you find the above much more elegant and readable than the other options?

Comment: I think this answer is valid for the question. OP didn't explicitly specify that he/she don't want to use third party libraries. I will compensate with +1.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add another (of many) options from a popular library (Apache Commons):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String joinedList = StringUtils.join(someList, ",");
```

See documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.String-

---

An elegant option from others' comments (as of Java 8):

```
String joinedList = someList.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```