# Java: How do I Convert List<Integers> to corresponding Strings

Tags: java

I have a List of Integers collected from a JSON. I want to change those integers for their corresponding string value and print those strings. 
For example: if my list of integers contains `4, 11, 67` and I know 4 means English, 11 means Bengali, 67 means Hindi. 
So, I want to convert them to their corresponding string and print them as `English, Bengali, Hindi`.

Here is a similar question's answer, but I want to change the integer value to its corresponding string value instead of just print those integers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198957/9920173

Every help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

An easier way to do this would be to use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and store the integer as the key and the String as the value. Something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> languages = new HashMap<>(); {{
    languages.put(4, "English");
    languages.put(11, "Bengali");
    //Etc
}}
```

Then when you want to print out the corresponding Strings you can do:

```
System.out.println(languages.get(4));
//Prints "English"
```

EDIT:

You can do something along these lines to print every corresponding String.

```
for(int num: yourList) {
   System.out.println(languages.get(num));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am new to this, so if you can help me. I get the list of integers from the server, how do I implement hashmap there and get their string value afterward?

Comment: @Arindam Do you want to print out all the corresponding Strings in your list? What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Let me explain, I get a List<Int> from the server. It may contain 1 integer or it may be 10. Now, every integer has their fixed corresponding String. Now whenever I get those list of integers no matter how many, their corresponding strings should print.

Answer (score 1):

Create an enum type to represent all the languages where an enum type's ordinal number is the integer value.

```
enum Language{
ASSAMESE,
...
ENGLISH//4th item
...
BENGALI//11th item
...
HINDI//67th item
...}
```

To get the language by the integer value say n:

```
Language.values()[n-1];
```

If you don't have languages for all integer values (say from 1, 2, 3,...n) you can use the below code:

```
public enum Language {
    ASSAMESE(1),
    ENGLISH(4),
    HINDI(67);

    private int langId;
    Language(int langId) {
        this.langId = langId;
    }

    public int getLangId() {
        return langId;
    }

    public void setLangId(int langId) {
        this.langId = langId;
    }

    public static Language getLanguageById(int langId) {
        for(Language lang : values()) {
            if(lang.getLangId() == langId) {
                return lang;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: That forces OP to fill in the gaps. Not good. You could instead have an enum with key, like ENGLISH(4) etc.

Comment: @Vasan I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: @Vasan Yes it makes sense. We can remove the setter method for langId.

Comment: @Vasan It also depends on our requirement. If langIds are not known until runtime we can provide default constructor and provide setter method. But in such a case we just want to handle a set of languages that we are interested in and we want to declare them as constant set of enum values.

Comment: Nope, in that case you wouldn't go for an enum - you would go for a normal class. Enum is meant for a fixed set of values you know beforehand. Having setters in an enum is technically allowed, but just really strange design.

Comment: @Vasan If you design as a class you cannot restrict more instances been created. As I said it depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can have number to language mapping in a `HashMap`. Then it can be implemented using Java 8 like so,

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(4, 11, 67);
Map<Integer, String> languageMap = new HashMap<>();
languageMap.put(4, "English");
languageMap.put(11, "Bengali");
languageMap.put(67, "Hindi");

String langStr = numbers.stream().map(languageMap::get).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

A possible imperative approach to solving the same problem would be like this.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (Integer number : numbers) {
    joiner.add(languageMap.get(number));
}
System.out.println(joiner.toString());
```

Still the latter solution necessitates the use of Java 8 since `StringJoiner` is available in Java 8.