# Convert a list of integers into a comma-separated string

Tags: java, java-8, integer, java-stream, collectors

I was trying to convert a list of Integers into a string of comma-separated integers.

**Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)  - Returns a Collector that concatenates the input elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order.**

```
List<Integer> i = new ArrayList<>();    //  i.add(null);
for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
    i.add(j);
}
System.out.println(i.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))); // Line 8
```

I am getting an error in line number 8:

> The method collect(Collector<? super Integer,A,R>) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#20-of ?,String>)

Is there a way to do this by streams in Java 8?

If I create a list of strings with `"1", "2", "3","4","5"`. it works.

Comment: You need to map the `Integer`s to `String`s` to use `joining`. It returns `Collector<CharSequence, ?, String>` specifically.

Comment: You can loop one more and give the value to string one by one with comma.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. However, there is no `Collectors.joining` for a `Stream<Integer>`; you need a `Stream<String>` so you should `map` before collecting. Something like,

```
System.out.println(i.stream().map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Which outputs

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Also, you could generate `Stream<Integer>` in a number of ways.

```
System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(1, 6).boxed().map(String::valueOf)
               .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
);
```

Comment: The method description says "Returns a Collector that concatenates the input elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order."  Shouldn't they mention input elements should only be String?

Comment: Also, i thought it will automatically calls toString method of Integer to solve this

Comment: Documentation also states: "*Returns: A Collector which concatenates **CharSequence** elements, separated by the specified delimiter, in encounter order"* (and return type is `Collector<CharSequence,​?,​String>`, that is, a `Collector` that accepts `CharSequence`)

Comment: @Naman what if i don't use overloaded method. I can also use `Collectors.joining()` which says "Returns a Collector that concatenates the input elements into a String, in encounter order."

Comment: If you read the ***entire*** definition, it says `static Collector<CharSequence,?,String> joining​(CharSequence delimiter)` which tells you the type it works on (`CharSequence`).

Comment: Instead of `.boxed().map(String::valueOf)`, you can use `.mapToObj(String::valueOf)`

Comment: Why should they mention what type the input elements need to be? The types (for parameters and return) are shown in the method signature. Java is statically typed so it wouldn't even compile if you provide the wrong type.

Answer (score 13):

It is very easy with the [Apache Commons Lang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons#Commons_Proper) library.

**Commons Lang**

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
String str = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(list, ","); // You can use any delimiter
System.out.println(str);  // Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

**Java 8 Solution**

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
String joinedList = list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(joinedList);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, simple, elegant, and does what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 3):

Using [Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)'s [com.google.common.base.Joiner](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html)

```
String res = Joiner.on(",").join(integerlist);
```

Using the Java Stream API

```
String res = integerlist.stream()
                        .map(String::valueOf)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer to your question could be:

`List.toString()` as below:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);
intList.add(3);

String listString = intList.toString();
System.out.println(listString); // <- this prints [1, 2, 3]
```

In this post below, it is very well explained. I hope you can find it useful:

*[Java: Convert List<Integer> to String](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13198957/8992452)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using `Spring` framework, they are providing a utility class for `String` operations `StringUtils`.

```
List<Integer> privileges = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

System.out.println(StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(privileges, ","));
```