# Print multiple lines of int value on one line as separated string

Tags: java

I am able to print an integer per line. For example:

```
1
2
3
```

I encounter errors when trying to put them into a list and output as a comma-separated string. For example, I'd like:

```
1,2,3
```

I encounter either the "int cannot be deferenced" or "cannot find symbol (Collectors)" error.

My error is in this block:

```
//System.out.println(value); // correctly prints each number on separate line

// errors
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();    
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(value.toString());
String result = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Full code is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("How many numbers: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int count = 0; count < size; count++){
            System.out.print("Enter value "+(count+1)+": ");
            int temp = input.nextInt();
            values.add(temp);
        }
        for(int value : values){
            //System.out.println(value); // correctly prints each number on separate line
            
            // errors
            ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();    
            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(value.toString());
            String result = myList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        }
    }
}
```

I was using these posts as reference but could not get the desired output.
[Convert list of integer into comma separated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602096/convert-list-of-integer-into-comma-separated-string)
[Error of int cannot be dereferenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28213083/error-of-int-cannot-be-dereferenced)

Comment: Try adding `map` into your stream pipeline to convert the integers to strings.

Comment: Add one of the following before `collect()`: `map(Integer::toString)`, `map(String::valueOf)`, `map(i -> Integer.toString(i))`, `map(i -> String.valueOf(i))`, `map(i -> "" + i)`

Comment: You don't need to loop through the `values` once again

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure I'm not implementing this as intended. For example, `String result = myList.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(","));` still gives an error.

Comment: `Integer::toString` is ambiguous. So provide complete lambda expression instead of the method reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map integers to string:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4);
String s = list.stream()
        .map(i->Integer.toString(i))   //<- covert to string
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: When I try this (using my list `ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();` nothing prints. I added some text to it so I know the line is printing, but no values are in the list?