# Iterating in Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I am trying to iterate the Arraylist in java and I want the output as -

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

I don't want to use the `for` loop. I want to use 'for each' loop to iterate and get the desired result. I want to iterate the list of lists in Arraylist. Here is my code for reference-

```java
package com.test.Day1;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ArrayListDemo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOflist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 
    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);
    
    listOflist.add(list1);
    
    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(4);
    list2.add(5);
    list2.add(6);
    
    listOflist.add(list2);
    
    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    list3.add(7);
    list3.add(8);
    list3.add(9);
    
    listOflist.add(list3);
    
    /*for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++){
        System.out.println(list1.get(i)+" "+list2.get(i)+" "+list3.get(i));
    }*/
    
    for(ArrayList<Integer> intList : listOflist){
        for(Integer intVal : intList){
            System.out.print(intVal);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Can someone please suggest how to proceed?

Comment: So you want to iterate without loop

Comment: by using a for loop, you are iterating it. Or what do you mean?

Comment: If you _know_ the size of all lists, you could just use something like `listOfLists.get(0).get(0) + " " + listOfLists.get(1).get(0) + " " + listOfLists.get(2).get(0)`. But that looks awful and is fragile as you often don't know the size of the lists at compile time. That's what loops and iterations are used for - so _why_ don't you want to use a loop? Or don't you want to use a `for` loop and and a `while` would be ok?

Comment: Actually I want to use for each loop. In my code I have iterated using for each but I am not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the values in 2D array and then use it to print the desired format -

```html
int [][] a = new int[listOflist.size()][listOflist.get(0).size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < listOflist.get(0).size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listOflist.size(); j++) {
                a[j][i] = listOflist.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }

        for (int[] ints : a) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(ints[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of possible solutions to choose from here is a question answered which is solving the print part of your inner list:

[Java: Convert List<Integer> to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198703/java-convert-listinteger-to-string/13198957)

Using the answer of **Hemmels** from the other post your code could look like this:

```java
public class ArrayListDemo3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOflist = new ArrayList<>(); // you don't have to supply type for initialization java does infer it(if unambiguous)
     
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(3);
        
        listOflist.add(list1);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(4);
        list2.add(5);
        list2.add(6);
        
        listOflist.add(list2);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        list3.add(7);
        list3.add(8);
        list3.add(9);
        
        listOflist.add(list3);
        
        for(ArrayList<Integer> intList : listOflist){
            System.out.println(
                    intList.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

edit: sorry compare corrected to 3:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listOflist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(1);
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(3);

    listOflist.add(list1);

    ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(4);
    list2.add(5);
    list2.add(6);

    listOflist.add(list2);

    ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    list3.add(7);
    list3.add(8);
    list3.add(9);

    listOflist.add(list3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        for (int x = 0; x < listOflist.size(); x++) {
            System.out.print(listOflist.get(x).get(i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: out of bounds exception

Comment: Sorry, I answered in horry at first. I tested this and output is as it should be.